# FTP Upload To random directory Wininet api

Tags: c++, c, ftp, wininet

i want to create and upload to randomly named directory in ftp using wininet
I use "randomseed" to upload files randomly named, but how to create & upload files into randomly named folders?Thank you

```
        FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, truepath, randomseed, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
        FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, truepath, randomseed, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);

        InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

        return 0;
```

Comment: Are you looking for `FtpCreateDirectory`?

Comment: FtpCreateDirectory(hFtpSession, randomseed);
  FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hFtpSession, randomseed);